# Java Script Undefined Error in mozilla?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use the following Javascript function.It will not work.It will give the **Undefined Error** in the following line, `c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip();`

```
function a()
{

    var table = getServerObject("b");
    var row,c;
    for (var i = 2; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++)
    {
        row = table.rows[i]; 
        if(row.cells.length==1)continue;
        c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip(); 
        if(c==0)
       {
        //Something
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: what does  getServerObject("b") return?

Comment: And what is the error...? and what is `strip()`? Did you mean `trim()`?

Comment: Did you try using a tool like firebug to know exactly what is undefined ? innerText ? c ?

Comment: I Get the Undefined Error.I use Error Console for debug

Comment: Probably, you need to use `row.cells.length<=1` instead of `row.cells.length==1`.

Comment: My feeling is `row.cells[0]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"continue" is the problem. see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

```
if(row.cells.length==1)continue;
```

The code should be like this

```
if(row.cells.length==1) {
    c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip(); 
}
```